# Removing sub header on specific pages(ionic)

Tags: html, ionic-framework

I am trying to hide a sub header with a button bar in it on specific pages, at the moment it is showing on all pages. I have a `nav` bar above that will remain on every page. Here is the code for the headers.

```
<ion-nav-bar class="bar-dark" align-title="center">

    <ion-nav-back-button></ion-nav-back-button>

    <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
        <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-ios-gear"></button>
    </ion-nav-buttons>

    <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
        <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-ios-cart-outline" ></button>
    </ion-nav-buttons>
</ion-nav-bar>





<ion-header-bar align-title="center" class="bar-subheader bar-light"  >
    <div class="button-bar">
        <a class="button button-outline button-dark">Sort</a>
        <a class="button button-outline button-dark">Categories</a>
        <a class="button button-outline button-dark">Filter</a>
    </div>

</ion-header-bar>
```

Thank you

Comment: did you tried to use `ng-hide` or `ng-show` or maybe `ng-if` to control when display it?

Comment: ng-hide hides the sub header on all views. ng-if and ng-show have no effect.

Comment: yeah, but you can pass it a parameter that you control from your controller, so in some cases you can hide it. Uhm you want to hide `ion-header-bar` ??

Comment: yes the ion-header-bar. i included ng-hide="!hide_subheader" in my HTML

my controller.js

.controller('SearchCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.hide_subheader = true;
})

app.js

 .state('tab.search', {
          url: '/search',
          views: {
              'search': {
                  templateUrl: 'templates/search.html',
                  controller: 'SearchCtrl'
              }
          }
      });

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment .You can control how to display your sub-header like this.

**HTML**

```
<ion-header-bar ng-hide="hideSub" ng-init="controlSubHeader()" align-title="center" class="bar-subheader bar-light"  >
<div class="button-bar">
    <a class="button button-outline button-dark">Sort</a>
    <a class="button button-outline button-dark">Categories</a>
    <a class="button button-outline button-dark">Filter</a>
</div>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
app.controller('MyController', function($state, $scope){
   $scope.hideSib = false;

   $scope.controlSubHeader = function(){
       if($state.current.name === 'tab.search')
       {
           $scope.hideSub = true;
       }else{
           $scope.hideSub = false;
       }
   }
});
```